# Training & plotting using python

Tags: python

I have a dataset which looks like this, [image]

I imported the data: # Load the data

```
df = pd.read_csv("payment_fraud.csv")

# Convert categorical feature into dummy variables with one-hot encoding
df = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['paymentMethod'])

# Print the column names of the DataFrame
print(df.columns)

Index(['accountAgeDays', 'numItems', 'localTime', 'paymentMethodAgeDays',
       'label', 'paymentMethod_creditcard', 'paymentMethod_paypal',
       'paymentMethod_storecredit'],
      dtype='object')
```

here is the issue I am making this plot below, and only the first 6 features have points not the rest of the graph.

```
tick_labels = ['mean radius', 'mean texture', 'mean area', 'mean smoothness', 'mean compactness', 'mean concavity', 'mean concave points', 'mean symmetry', 'mean fractal dimension', 'radius error', 'texture error', 'perimeter error', 'area error', 'smoothness error', 'compactness error', 'concavity error', 'concave points error', 'symmetry error', 'fractal dimension error', 'worst radius', 'worst texture', 'worst perimeter', 'worst area', 'worst smoothness', 'worst compactness', 'worst concavity', 'worst concave points', 'worst symmetry', 'worst fractal dimension']

# Set tick locations
tick_locations = np.arange(len(tick_labels))

# Plot logistic regression coefficients
plt.figure(figsize=(14, 8)) # increase figure size
plt.axhline(y=0, color='black', linestyle='-')
plt.plot(lr_models[0].coef_.T, 'o', color='blue', label=f"C={C_params[0]}")
plt.plot(lr_models[1].coef_.T, '^', color='red', label=f"C={C_params[1]}")
plt.plot(lr_models[2].coef_.T, 'v', color='lime', label=f"C={C_params[2]}")
plt.xticks(tick_locations, tick_labels, rotation=90, fontsize=8) # reduce font size
plt.ylim([-5, 5])
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

I had trained the data like this: # Split data into training and testing sets

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df.drop(columns=['label']), df['label'], test_size=0.33, random_state=42)

# Build logistic regression models with different C parameters
C_params = [1, 100, 10, 0.01, 0.001]
lr_models = []
for C in C_params:
    lr = LogisticRegression(C=C)
    lr.fit(X_train, y_train)
    lr_models.append(lr)
    print(f"Training set score (C={C}): {lr.score(X_train, y_train)}")
    print(f"Test set score (C={C}): {lr.score(X_test, y_test)}")
    print()
```

if it helps here is my plot
[image]

here is what i need
[image]

here is some of the data, theres 370000 records in total
accountAgeDays,numItems,localTime,paymentMethod,paymentMethodAgeDays,label
29,1,4.745402,paypal,28.2048611111,0
725,1,4.742303,storecredit,0.0,0
845,1,4.921318,creditcard,0.0,0
503,1,4.886641,creditcard,0.0,0
2000,1,5.040929,creditcard,0.0,0
119,1,4.962055,paypal,0.0,0
2000,1,4.921349,paypal,0.0,0
371,1,4.876771,creditcard,0.0,0
2000,1,4.748314,creditcard,0.0,0
4,1,4.461622,creditcard,0.0,0
26,1,4.745402,paypal,0.0,0
2000,1,4.505662,creditcard,0.000694444444444,0
3,1,4.962055,creditcard,2.69097222222,0
3,1,4.921318,creditcard,2.06944444444,0
23,1,4.745402,creditcard,0.00138888888889,0
5,1,4.921349,paypal,4.03611111111,0
1208,1,4.836982,creditcard,0.000694444444444,0
11,1,4.921349,creditcard,10.8659722222,0
123,1,4.748314,creditcard,0.000694444444444,0
2000,1,4.895263,creditcard,248.774305556,0